# The return of the line int%=2 in java, and the actual behaviour of the statement

Tags: java

my appologies for a rather simple question,
but i wanted to ask about the % operator.
If we iterate from 0 up untill any big number and have code

```
        int++;
        int %= 2;
```

what exactly does it do?
do we set the `//int=int%2`
?
how would it work with the example of the actual numbers, and what does the line `int %= 2;`  return?

```
   private void play() {
        // while the board does not have a winner neither is full
        while(!board.hasWinner() && !board.isFull()) {
            //print the state of the game
            update();
            //set field for the current player and the passed mark
            board.setField(players[current].determineMove(board), players[current].getMark());
            //go to the next player
            current++;
            // current= current % 2
            //
            current %= 2;
        }
        update();
        printResult();
    }
```

where the current comes from:

```
  private int current;

    // -- Constructors -----------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates a new Game object.
     * @requires s0 and s1 to be non-null
     * @param s0 the first player
     * @param s1 the second player
     */
    public Game(Player s0, Player s1) {
        board = new Board();
        players = new Player[NUMBER_PLAYERS];
        players[0] = s0;
        players[1] = s1;
        current = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well, that code doesn't compile, so it won't do much of anything.  Can you provide a little more context as to what you're trying to do? (A [mcve] would be ideal)

Comment: yes, i am designing a game , and i need to iterate through my players. The friend of mine suggested to use the line int%=2; to keep going from person 1 to person 2. However , i do not understand how it works in that case

Comment: Well, generally speaking `%` is the remainder operator, so for instance, `1 % 2` would give `1`, and `2 % 2` would give `0`.  I have no idea how that would help you switch between players, though, since it's not like `%=` is going to flip between different values.  Once a variable is 1 or 0, it'll stay that way if you apply `%=` to it.

Comment: i will add the method in the question , for some reason it works but i cannot explain it

Comment: oh, i see! Thank you a lot !

Comment: It is also possible to use `current = 1 - current;` to make it toggle from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    j++;
    j %= 2;
    System.out.print(j + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

You can achieve it in one line for neater code:

```
j = ++j % 2;
```